# Selenium Chromedriver disable log on Windows

Tags: python, selenium, logging, crash

I am running **selenium** via **python 3** with the **chromedriver** browser on **windows 10**.

The program is very active and should run constantly. Means: lots of logging going on.

**Problem**: the crhomedriver logs get way too long after a few hours, and windows tends to crash.

[image]

Everything is working fine, the logs are just minor issues about which I do not really care.

**Question**:

How may I disable the **chromedriver** logs?

**Notes**:

- I did my research and did not find any working solution yet.
- I am forced to use chromedriver, hence no headless browser like phantomJS is a valid alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, not sure it will work. Pass the options to your chromedriver

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--disable-logging')
```

Comment: With `driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)`

Comment: It seemed to work at the beginning. But no. It did not.

Comment: This neither: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options,service_log_path='NUL')`